# Error guardarbusqueda is not a function. guardarbusqueda' is an instance of Object

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Presento el siguiente error :TypeError: guardarbusqueda is not a function. (In 'guardarbusqueda((0, _extends2.default)({}, busqueda, {
pais: pais
}))', 'guardarbusqueda' is an instance of Object)

A continuación mi código

Formulario.js

En este archivo js he colocado todo con respecto al formulario en este caso un picker para seleccionar un país y botón para que al presionarlo consulte una api y pueda obtener información de los países.

```
import  React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, View, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback,Animated,Alert }
from 'react-native';
import {Picker} from '@react-native-community/picker';
const Formulario=(busqueda,guardarbusqueda)=>{
const {pais}=busqueda;
const [animacionboton]=useState(new Animated.Value(1));

const consultarPais=()=>{
  if(pais.trim()===''){
    mostarAlerta();
    return;
  }
  //Consultar API
 guardarconsultar(true);
};

const mostarAlerta=()=>{
    Alert.alert('Error','Debe seleccionar un país'),[{Text:'Entendido'}];
};

const animacionEntrada=()=>{
    Animated.spring(animacionboton,{
        toValue:.9,
        useNativeDriver: true // Add This line
    }).start();
  };

  const animacionSalida=()=>{
     Animated.spring(animacionboton,{
       toValue:1,
       useNativeDriver: true // Add This line
      }).start();
  };

  const estiloAnimacion={
    transform:[{
      scale:animacionboton
    }]
  };


return(
<>
<View>
<View>
<Text style ={styles.input}>Pais</Text>
</View>
<View>
<Picker 
selectedValue={pais}
onValueChange={pais=>guardarbusqueda({...busqueda,pais})}

onPress={()=>consultarPais()}
style={styles.itempais}>
<Picker.Item label="--seleccione un pais--" value=""/>
<Picker.Item label="El Salvador" value="sv"/>
<Picker.Item label="Guatemala" value="gt"/>
<Picker.Item label="Honduras" value="hn"/>
<Picker.Item label="Nicaragua" value="ni"/>
<Picker.Item label="Panama" value="pa"/>
<Picker.Item label="Costa Rica" value="cr"/>
<Picker.Item label="Mexico" value="mx"/>
<Picker.Item label="Argentina" value="ar"/>
<Picker.Item label="Estados Unidos" value="us"/>
<Picker.Item label="Colombia" value="co"/>
<Picker.Item label="España" value="es"/>
<Picker.Item label="Peru" value="pe"/>
</Picker>
</View>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback 
onPressIn={()=>animacionEntrada()} 
onPressOut={()=>animacionSalida()}
>

<Animated.View style={styles.btnBuscar}>
<Text style={styles.textoBuscar}>Buscar País</Text>
</Animated.View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles= StyleSheet.create({
input:{padding:10,
height:50,
fontSize:20,
marginBottom:20,
textAlign:'center',
color :'#000'
},
itempais:{
height:60,
backgroundColor:'#fff',
},
btnBuscar:{
marginTop:50,
height:50,
backgroundColor:'#000',
fontSize:20,
marginBottom:20,
textAlign:'center'
},
textoBuscar:{
color:'#fff',
fontWeight:'bold',
textTransform:'uppercase',
textAlign:"center",
fontSize:18
}
})
export default Formulario;
```

Pais.js

En este archivo js un componente card para mostrar la información del país seleccionado.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
const Pais = ({ resultado }) => {
const { capital, name, subregion, region } = resultado;
return (
<Card>
<Card.Title>{name}</Card.Title>
<Card.Divider />
<View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
<Text>Capital:{capital}</Text>
<Text>Region:{region}</Text>
<Text>Subregion:{subregion}</Text>
</View>
</Card>
);
};
export default Pais;
```

index.js

En este archivo js he colocado toda la lógica de la aplicación.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {Text,View,StyleSheet,Alert,AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Formulario from './src/components/Formulario';
import Pais from './src/components/Pais';
export default function App(){

const [busqueda,guardarbusqueda]=useState({
  pais:'',
});

const [consultar,guardarconsultar]=useState(false);
const [resultado,guardarresultado]=useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
  
  const {pais} = busqueda;
    const consultarPais = async () => {
      if(consultar){
        const url='https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${pais}';
        try{
          const respuesta = await fetch(url);
          const resultado = await respuesta.json();

          guardarresultado(resultado);
          guardarconsultar(false);
        }catch(error){
          mostrarAlerta();
        }
      }
    };
    consultarPais();
},[consultar]);

const mostrarAlerta=()=>{
  Alert.alert('Error','No hay resultado intenta con otra ciudad o país'),[{Text:'Ok'}];
};

return(
<View>
  <View>
  <Formulario
  busqueda={busqueda}
  guardarbusqueda={guardarbusqueda}
 guardarconsultar={guardarconsultar}
  />
<Pais resultado={resultado}/>
  </View>
  </View>
  
);


}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('paises', () => App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que se esta usando un antipatrón en la declaración del  componente `Formulario`, hay dos formas para pasar parametros:

- Destructurar
- Pasar el parametro `props`

El error aquí no muestra el mensaje, pero si se corre esta pieza de código en VSCODE se mostrará el mensaje:

> TypeError: guardarbusqueda is not a function. (In 'guardarbusqueda({ ...busqueda,
> pais: city
> })', 'guardarbusqueda' is an instance of Object)

```js
function App(){
  const [busqueda,guardarbusqueda]=React.useState({pais:'',});
  return (
   <div>
     <Formulario
      busqueda={busqueda}
      guardarbusqueda={guardarbusqueda}/>
   </div>
  )
}
//Aqui hay un antipatron
//o se destructuran los parametros
//o se pasa el parametro props
const Formulario=(busqueda,guardarbusqueda)=>{

React.useEffect(()=>{
   let city = "Sin City";
   guardarbusqueda({...busqueda,pais:city});
},[]);

return <p>"in Formulario Comp:" {busqueda.pais}</p>
}
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Este es el patrón correcto:

```js
function App(){
  const [busqueda,guardarbusqueda]=React.useState({pais:'',});
  return (
   <div>
     <Formulario
      busqueda={busqueda}
      guardarbusqueda={guardarbusqueda}/>
   </div>
  )
 }
//se destructuran los parametros
const Formulario=({busqueda,guardarbusqueda})=>{

React.useEffect(()=>{
   let city = "Sin City";
   guardarbusqueda({...busqueda,pais:city});
},[]);

return <p>"In Formulario Comp:" {busqueda.pais}</p>
}
 ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Lo he probado y siempre me aparece el mismo mensaje de error.

Comment: Sugiero que des una doble revisión a tu código,  te deje una demostración funcional.

Comment: lo que me ocasiona problemas es lo siguiente : onValueChange={pais=>guardarbusqueda({...busqueda,pais})}

Comment: Claro, el componente `Formulario` nos esta diciendo que `guardarbusqueda` no es una función, no la reconoce porque no la estamos destructurando en la declaración: `const Formulario=(busqueda,guardarbusqueda)=>{`; Debe ir así : `const Formulario=({busqueda,guardarbusqueda})=>{`, te lo demostré en el ejemplo.